# Как написать оконное приложение?

Tags: windows, c++, visual-studio

Хочу писать в Visual Studio хотя можно и в чём-нибудь другом, **язык С++**.

Посоветуйте книги, статьи. Слышал в VS есть Windows Forms, только методом тыка не получилось разобраться.

**Поступили предложения использовать Windows Forms, WPF, MFC и Qt. Так, а что лучше?**

Comment: @Soul Сравнение MFC, Windows Forms, WPF, Qt - это отдельный вопрос, который правильно задать в новой теме.

Answer (score 6):

Первым шагом стоит скачать и установить на свою машину [Visual C++ Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2010-Visual-CPP) (если она еще не установлена). Вторым шагом зайти на страницу MSDN [Создание приложений Win32 (C++)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb384843(v=VS.100).aspx) и выполнить по пунктам все, что там написано. Третьим шагом заглянуть в раздел [Интерактивный учебник по Visual C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms235630.aspx): там есть, что почитать. Возможно, и книги не понадобятся. :)

По WinForms: это устаревшая технология, тратить время на ее изучение сейчас нет смысла. Если по работе понадобится, тогда да, можно и поизучать, а так лучше ознакомиться с [WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms754130.aspx).

Comment: WPF на C++ нельзя использовать и даже на C++/CLI тоже нельзя. А WinForms только на C++/CLI (мы тут не говорим про другие .net языки).

Answer (score 1):

Почитайте "Visual C++ и MFC" Мешков А., Тихомиров Ю.

Несмотря на то что давно издана, на мой взгляд самая доходчивая книга про использование MFC.
А Windows Forms не получиться использовать на C++ (как уже написал в одном из комментариев). Поскольку Windows Forms доступен только на платформе .NET и язык должен быть соответствующим, например C++/CLI.

Comment: Это почему Windows Forms не получиться использовать? 
У меня Visual Studio 2010 стоит и в разделе Visual C++ есть Windows Forms Application.

Comment: придется нехило поизвращаться, если прям плюсы и прям вижуал студия - то уж лучше MFC. Но я бы посоветовал глянуть в сторону Qt ;-)

Comment: @Soul Чтобы писать для WinForms на С++, надо использовать C++/CLI. Это по сути отдельный, хотя и близко родственный к C++, язык.

Answer (score 0):

Привет :) 
Не слушай **usrex**-а :))))

Методом тыка, конечно же, не получится :) 
Читай книги по Шилдту :) Он очень явно и понятно расписывает все :) 
P.S. При чтении бывают моменты, что ничего не понятно. Ну да ничего. Как правило, при переходе на следующую статью очень быстро осиняют правильные идеи и мысли по отношению к предыдущей.

P.P.S. Сначала научись писать консольные приложения. После этого уже к Win-формам переходи, ибо если начинать учить с середины - маловероятно, что это чем-то толковым для тебя выдет.

Comment: Консольные умею писать. В Шилдте разве есть про оконные приложения?
И какую именно советуешь книгу его, а то по той ссылке, кот. ты дал, там их много.

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, тут есть описание: 
http://www.twirpx.com/file/12299/

Comment: Просмотрел содержание, ничего про оконные приложения нет, тока консоль.

Answer (score -7):

Правильный ответ на твой вопрос: Python + GTK.

С++ не предназначен для создания GUI. А Qt -- историческая случайность.

Comment: Тогда уж можно сразу на tcl/tk писать - и никакого питона не потребуется.

Comment: Не, ну Tcl/Tk классный, только вот

Страшноват
Язык будет многим непривычен

Comment: То же самое можно сказать про Python - некоторым без указателей вообще жизнь не мила.

Comment: C++ универсальный язык программирования т.е. для "всего". Говорить, что он для чего то не предназначен, значит не понимать его.

Comment: С++ язык без ниши. Доказано VSL.

Единственное в чём C++ востребован, так это в gamedev. И то, наверное дань традициям. Может быть для написания виртуальных машин, которые обязаны быть быстрыми, но бывает не хватает выразительности Си.

Пусть тебе нужно сделать морду к БД. На чём это легче и быстрее написать? Точно не на C++ с его утечками памяти, сегфолтами и прочими радостями жизни. Сделать тоже самое на Python -- гораздо легче и быстрее.

Comment: @Vladimir VG offtop, смотрите теги - C++

Comment: Не обижайте Tool Command Language. Его и так Столман сколько лет ругал. Хороший, выразительный язык. Написал на нем несколько приложений остался очень доволен =)

Comment: Согласен, язык классный. Метапрограмминг, все дела. Совсем как lisp.